# Execute multiple objects' methods at the same time using Executed Service

Tags: java, multithreading, traffic

I am trying to build a traffic light system to control a junction. I have a Controller class that will execute the phases of the junction for instance the first phase will turn the South-North and North-South traffic lights to green light for a certain amount of time using Thread.sleep and then the same in the second phase but for East-West and West-East traffic lights.

my problem is I want turn all the traffic lights in each phase together so South-North and North-South traffic light will become green and go red at the same time. I have tried to use ExecutedService framework but it does not seem to be working properly here is my code. if you need any further information in order to give me a useful answers please don't hesitate to ask

this is the controller class' start method that will run the phases consecutively the controller has the phases as a list of object LinkedList.

```
public void start() throws Exception {

        // if there are no phases(cycles) to be executed in sequence
        if (phases.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("There are no phases been created for the intersection to be controlled");
        }

        Iterator<Phase> iteratorP = phases.iterator();

        //execute phases in sequence
        while (iteratorP.hasNext()) {
            Phase phase = iteratorP.next();
            System.out.println("phase activated: ");
            // will activate the phase by turning all the traffic lights in this phase to green light
            phase.activate();

        }
    }
```

====================================
this is the phases class. this class will have a list of traffic lights list that will be turned to green and then red for certain amount of time

```
protected void activate() {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(trafficLights.size());
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (TrafficLight tl : trafficLights) {

                    tl.nextState();
                    System.out.println("TrafficLight nextState done");

                    try {
                        //PrepareToStopSate = Amber Light
                        //PrepareToGoState = Amber + Red Lights

                        if (tl.getCurrentState() instanceof PrepareToStopState ||
                            tl.getCurrentState() instanceof PrepareToGoState) {
                            System.out.println("wait 2sec");

                            //will wait for two seconds then chnage the state to next state GoState or StopState
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(pause * 1000);
                            System.out.println("TL nextState done");
                            tl.nextState();
                        } else {
                            //if the state of the traffic light is either GoState(green) or StopState(red)
                            //wait for (duration) time then change the state
                            System.out.println("wait duration for green and red");
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(duration * 1000);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your code, only one thread will run the one in the *execute* method of your ExecutorService (you only execute one Runnable in your code!).

Again if my understanding is correct, you should have each **TrafficLight implement Runnable** and then have a code like:

```
protected void activate(){
//some code
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(trafficLights.size());    
for (TrafficLight tl: trafficLights){
          executor.execute(tl);
    }
//some other code
}
```

Also instead of using Thread.sleep(), you might want to take a look to the [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) class.

For the class with Runnable, that's where you implement the logic, so given your code it would look like:

```
public class TrafficLight implement Runnable{

//Some methods
@Override
public void run(){

                    tl.nextState();
                    System.out.println("TrafficLight nextState done");

                    try {
                        //PrepareToStopSate = Amber Light
                        //PrepareToGoState = Amber + Red Lights

                        if (tl.getCurrentState() instanceof PrepareToStopState ||
                            tl.getCurrentState() instanceof PrepareToGoState) {
                            System.out.println("wait 2sec");

                            //will wait for two seconds then chnage the state to next state GoState or StopState
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(pause * 1000);
                            System.out.println("TL nextState done");
                            tl.nextState();
                        } else {
                            //if the state of the traffic light is either GoState(green) or StopState(red)
                            //wait for (duration) time then change the state
                            System.out.println("wait duration for green and red");
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(duration * 1000);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }
}
```

Comment: after I implement the Runnable  interface what should be the implementation of the run() method? only what you have given? and your code in which class should it be?

Comment: Your answer is very clear but is that going to turn all the traffic lights in the first phase together without touching the traffic lights in the next phases ?

Comment: I see that you used the traffic light class to write the logic. Cannot that be from the Phase or Controller?

Comment: You asked about executor service, that's the aim of my answer. I can't say much about the logic of traffic lights unfortunately. I would suggest you try to implement a controller that will handle the threads to maintain a coherent state between your group of traffic lights .

Comment: Ok I understand but in order to make each traffic light a thread or works independently and simultaneously, the traffic light must implement the Runnable interface? Thanks again for your help

Comment: It depends mainly on what you consider a unit of work: is it a traffic light or a group of traffic light? That will give you what should implement Runnable or Callable

Comment: Group of traffic light